# SAP BPC EPM dynamic table member

Tags: sap-epm

I'm quiet new with BPC and I struggle right now with something looking easy.
I basically have a table splitted in 3 parts. In the first 2 data are coming from a cube in the 3rd part (IN RED), data are calculated with excel formulas 
FORMULA of cell D33 :(=D26 - D40)
....[image]
This work perfectly as long as the dimension doesn't move, if I add a new member then all formualas and number are shifted and don't match anymore..
What would be the solution to solve that and stay dynamic ? 
I tried several option like EPMFormattingSheet , Excel formulas, Local member and formulas :(((
Has anybody an idea on how to solve that ?
Thank you very much
E.

Answer (score 0):

Local members with formulas should work for your case